# newline charachter use in typecasting

Tags: python

so i just started learning python so please be humble i am still a noob so this is my code

```
x="hello world"
y=45
z=45.7
w=65
v="harry"
print(y+z)
print(y+w)
print(x+v)
print(type(x))
print(type(y))
print(type(z))
#read explanation from notes 
#lets start with typecasting
m="52"
n="34"
print(m+n)
print(int(m)+int(n))
print(float(m)+float(n))
#this code is for conversion into different types
x=5
print(x*"hello world \n")             
print(x*"hello world")
print(x*str(int(m)+int(n)))
```

here in the last statement i tried to print it with a new line character like this

```
print(X*str(int(m)+int(n)\n))
```

and this input returned an error like this

```
     print(x*str(int(m)+int(n))\n)
                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

i tried inserting the newline character here and there but it did not work how do i make it print in new lines using new line character

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `+` to concatenate strings. You also have to put `\n` inside quotes. And add parentheses to specify the grouping, since `*` has higher precedence than `+`.

```
print(x * (str(int(m) + int(n)) + "\n"))
```

You can also simplify this by using a format string.

```
print(x * f'{int(m)+int(n)}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the newline character you have to surround it with quotation marks like this `"\n"` or `'\n'`. Otherwise it won't be interpreted as a string.

So your command could look like this `print((x*str(int(m)+int(n)))+"\n")` if you want to print the newline once or like this `print(x*(str(int(m)+int(n))"\n"))` if you need a newline after each `(str(int(m)+int(n)`.